# Unable to parse hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I'm unable to parse hibernate.cfg.xml and geting

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg", local:"hibernate-configuration"). Expected elements are <{}hibernate-configuration>
```

It can be something with xml parser, it seams like it uses stax under the hood. We are on hibernate 5.2.3. The header of our  hibernate.cfg.xml file is correct I tried both Xsd

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding='utf-8'?>
<hibernate-configuration
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <session-factory>
```

and DTD

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration
    PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
```

Both have the same error. I must be something with the parser.

**UPDATE**
I have fixed the question code was not properly visible. I'm sure the XML is valid XML.

**UPDATE 2**
I start to get some clues. It can be caused by running the code as junit powermock test. Specifically `com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl` class reading the file, is loaded by MockClassLoader.

**UPDATE 3**
They solved it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34897047/2944265) by taming powermock a little b

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.sax.*" })
```

Now I have different error hope I'm on the right track.

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)Ljava/lang/Object;" the class loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) of the current class, com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/runtime/unmarshaller/UnmarshallerImpl, and its superclass loader (instance of <bootloader>), have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/Node used in the signature
```

That is resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21558249/2944265) by adding additional classes to the

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.sax.*", "com.sun.xml.*", "com.sun.org.*"})
```

Comment: can you check somewhere in the config file, have you missed `<` or `>` symbol

Comment: also, look into this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203312/javax-xml-bind-unmarshalexception-unexpected-element-uri-localgroup

Comment: Please, add your `hibernate.cfg.xml`, at least part.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm experiencing this too (using Java 9, if that matters).

Comment: The update 3 fixed my error completely. Have you tried that? Or do you have other issues?

Answer (score 0):

can you try to change and use this template for hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="domain">

  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
  <mapping package="com.example.dao.entity"/>

  <!-- etc -->

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error was raised in Hibernate 5.4.4 while using `java version "14.0.1"`.

> unexpected element (uri:"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg", local:"hibernate-configuration"). Expected elements are <{}hibernate-configuration>

A simple downgrade to `java 8` resolve it.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.4/) the Hibernate up  to 5.4.4. supports Java `8` or `11`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but the fix was simple.  I added the correct default namespace to the hibernate.cfg.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration">
    <session-factory>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```