# Junit 4.x + Hibernate 5.x with H2 database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit4, powermockito

I am not using any framework just using maven war module and want to test the DAO layer using Juit 4 + Powermockito (first time).

My idea is when I call CustomerDao to test createCustomer. First statement of this method is as below:

```
Session session = HibernateManager.getInstance().getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

I want to mock this call so that I can provide the session object which I constructed in the test class using following code:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import com.dao.CustomerDao;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

public class CustomerDaoTest {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Mock
    CustomerDao customer=new CustomerDao();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
        }

    @Test
    public void CustomerCreateAndDeleteTest() throws Exception {
        // Want to mock here
        int id=customer.createCustomer("Indian Customer", "India", "xyz@pk.com", 
        "234567890", "AB");
        Assert.assertEquals(1, id);
     }

    private SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.h2.xml");// Using H2 for testing only
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Problem is:

1. When I run my test class I am getting error:

> org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to
>   perform unmarshalling at line number -1 and column -1 in RESOURCE
>   hibernate.cfg.h2.xml. Message: unexpected element
>   (uri:"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg",
>   local:"hibernate-configuration"). Expected elements are
>   <{}hibernate-configuration>

But if I remove annotation `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`
then I am not getting this error.

2. How can I mock the method call which is inside the createCustomer() method as below:
       `Session session = HibernateManager.getInstance().getSessionFactory().openSession();`

Please guide me how I can write Unit test case to test the DAO layer which can use a different `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

Comment: Mocking a Session to test your DAO is basically useless. Your DAO's responsibility is to get data from the database using queries. So basically, what you need to check is that the query is correct and returns the correct values from the database. Mocking the session will just check that you're executing a query. You still won't know if the query is correct, and if it returns the correct data. Don't use mocks to test your DAOs. Instead, populate your database with test data at the beginning of the test, call your DAO, and check it returned the right data.

Comment: Mocking the DAO that you're testing is even more incorrect: you won't even execute a single line of your code, but instead test that Mockito works fine.

Comment: Thanks Prashant for you response but in my case there are standard method used to save the object like session.save() I want to check whether the object is persisted properly or not by using my assertion in the test case.

Comment: Which is precisely why you shouldn't mock your DAO or the Hibernate session. If you mock it, all its methods are mocked, and do nothing. So you can't check that they're correctly doing their job. And my name is JB Nizet, not Prashant.

Comment: Ahh! sorry JB thank you very much for your response. Can you tell me if I want to test my curd operations then what should be the approach. Because If i don't mock the session then if I call the method from test class it will make entry in the database which I do not want, and that is why I want to use in memory data base H2, Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You DO want to insert an entry in your database. This database is just not your production database but your test, in-memory H2 database. So nothing should be mocked. You should just configure your tests to use a persistence configuration that uses your in-memory H2 database rather than your production database, that's all. That said, I would advise against using a different database: you'll test that your code works against H2, but you still won't know if it works against your actual database.

Comment: Thanks JB! I have done the same I am able to check all the operations using the H2 for now. But I think I should test in my Dev DB and should not use H2 am I correct JB.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be PowerMocks classloader.

[Unable to parse hibernate.cfg.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554697/unable-to-parse-hibernate-cfg-xml)

I got PowerMock, JUnit4, and Hibernate to work in JDK11 following the same principal, and adding the following to my Class:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "org.hibernate.*"})
```

Full class example:
`org.hibernate hibernate-core 5.4.2.Final (compile)`
`junit junit:4.12 (test)`
`net.bytebuddy byte-buddy 1.9.10 (compile)`
`org.powermock powermock-module-junit4 2.0.2 (test)`
`com.h2database h2 1.4.199 (test)`

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "org.hibernate.*"})
public class PowerMockHibernateTest {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public PowerMockHibernateTest() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    private Session getNewSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    @Test
    public void getQuery() {
        Session session = getNewSession();
        session.createNamedQuery("PostEntity.All", PostEntity.class);
    }

    private SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.h2.xml");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.h2.Driver");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```